# Compiler for RISC-V vector code generation

Tags: vectorization, riscv, instruction-set

Is there a compiler available which generates the vector instructions according to the new vector extension proposed in RISC-V ISA specification v2.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such a compiler does not exist. The vector extension is still being written but there should be a more complete draft and progress on a toolchain by the next RISC-V workshop.

Answer (score 0):

As of early 2020, there are [binutil/gcc branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60139153/427158) that support the current RISC-V Vector Extension "V" 0.8 draft.

That means with that experimental toolchain, you can use vector instruction in assembly code and in inline assembler constructs.

It's unclear if that GCC RISC-V "V" support already extends to auto-vectorization.

Vector intrinsics also aren't available, yet.

Comment: that`s not an answer, i think it`s just a comment.

Comment: @АлексейХилаев No, it isn't just a comment. My answer directly answers OP's question.