# How to use vector operations in RISC-V Assembly

Tags: assembly, simd, riscv

I am trying to exploit vector operations in RISC-V Assembly, in particular I need to compile my source code with arch RV64iV or RV64GV.
I am using riscv64-unknown-elf- toolchain, with the following parameters:

riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -o test -march=rv32iv test.s

but I get the following error:

Assembler messages:
Fatal error: -march=rv32iv: unsupported ISA subset `v'

Thanks

Comment: Try to update your toolchain.

Comment: [This post](https://www.embecosm.com/2018/09/09/supporting-the-risc-v-vector-extension-in-gcc-and-llvm/) about RISC-V Vector Extensions from September 2018 says that _"At present there has been no implementation work or experimentation conducted with GCC"_.

Comment: @Michael: But does that just mean no auto-vectorization or intrinsics that will get GCC to emit the instructions?  GNU Binutils is a separate project and could have implemented the asm instructions even if gcc never emits them.  (`gcc` on a .s just feeds the asm file to `as` from binutils.  `-march` options are usually meaningless when only assembling, not compiling, but can matter on ARM for thumb vs. ARM...  Probably not for RISC-V)

Comment: @PeterCordes: No idea. That was the information I could find. I haven't built binutils myself lately so I don't have any recent source distribution.

Comment: My comment was partly addressed at the OP: they should try `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc test.s` and see what the assembler says, instead of erroring out the GCC front-end.

Answer (score 1):

As of February 2019 there is no standard RISC-V vector extension, which means there is no support in standard RISC-V toolchains.  There are various drafts of the vector extension floating around, but nothing supported by software.

Answer (score 1):

As of early 2020, the RISC-V vector extension "V" specification is at version 0.8 and still has draft status.

However, there are "V" ports of the GNU gcc/binutils available and the Spike RISC-V simulator supports "V" 0.8, as well. The [README of the "V" spec links to the relevant branches](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-v-spec#additional-resources).

I recently published [some notes](https://gms.tf/riscv-vector.html#getting-started) on how to get started with RISC-V "V" 0.8  development, e.g. how to build the right toolchain, related components, assemble, compile "V" code and how to test it with Spike.